# Joomla: Error 500 View not found when requesting subcontroller response

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I'm trying to return the result of a task from a subcontroller with the following url:

```
index.php?option=com_example&task=subctrl.test&format=json
```

but I keep getting the `500 View not found` Error...

```
class ExampleControllersSubctrl extends JControllerForm
{
    public function test()
    {
                $result= array("val1","val2");
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

I've tried naming the subcontroller file both Subctrl.php & Subctrl.json.php but neither worked. I believe I shouldn't need a view to render the result based on other SO posts I've read but maybe that is incorrect.

This setup will eventually be used to return an Ajax call when I get it working.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Add an exit statement after the echo statement or Joomla will continue processing the component and will try to call a view. Since no view value was set, no view will be found and the system will redirect to an error page. Full code below:

```
class ExampleControllerSubctrl extends JControllerForm
{
    public function test()
    {
        $result= array("val1","val2");
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Joomla also some other methods that you can use such as call `jexit()` or `JFactory::getApplication()->close()`. The general idea is to get the application to stop here. Continuing is a waste.

Also, had to make sure the class name is set right. Middle work should be `Controller` not `Controllers`.

Comment: Thanks for the response David! I tried your suggestion (all 3 versions but still getting the same error. What else could be wrong?

Comment: In that case, the function isn't even getting called. And that is likely because your class is named wrong. Should be `ExampleControllerSubctrl` (Controller not Controllers).

Comment: Hi David, after some experimentation I figured out that it depends on the name of the containing folder so if folder is named controllers it's ExampleControllersSubctrl or if it's called controller you drop the s in the class name. I think the problem might be that it's not possible to have more than the execute function in the controller if you are using the J3 MVC model but I might be wrong about that. I might try creating a new controller for the ajax call but maybe thats not the correct way to go about it...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're extending `JControllerForm` which will try and guess the `view` for your `form` if one isn't provided.

On Joomla 2.5 you can change `JControllerForm` to `JController` and that will resolve the problem.

As you have a `JSON` controller that Joomla is routing you to via `format=json` you don't need an exit on your `test()` method either.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I've tried changing to JController but still no luck... Anything else I can try?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Can you add you directory structure for your component to the question, including file names… it seems like Joomla may not be routing to your JSON controller. What do you have in your `example.php` and `controller.php`?

Comment: Hi I'll add the dir structure and other code in an hour or 2 when I have a bit more time but I've added a syntax error into the controller to check if joomla was routing through it and yes it broke the layout... so it looks like it is! Also which is correct Subctrl.php or Subctrl.json.php? (I've tried both!)

Comment: I think the problem could be the fact that I'm using the J3 MVC model and I'm not sure but it's possible that a separate sub controller is required for all tasks...

Comment: `subctrl.json.php` would be the correct name for the url you have in your question `index.php?option=com_example&task=subctrl.test&format=json`

Comment: I'm confused how are you calling that URL, can you add the Javascript you have to call the JSON controller, adding an error to your JSON controller should not break your layout which should be handled by the view's controller.